# Full list symbols stripped with str.strip() by default

Tags: python, string, strip, removing-whitespace

As said in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20strip#str.strip):

> str.strip([chars])
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.

What is **whitespace**?

```
   import string    
   print(string.whitespace)
```

gives smth like `' \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'`

in the same time,

```
'\t\n\r\f\x85\x1c\x1d\v\u2028\u2029'.strip()
```

gives '' too.

So the question is: what is the full list of symbols striped by default with str.strip()?
Sorry but GPT says [rubbish](https://sl.bing.net/h0DLiPy4v36) on it.

Comment: May be. But it looks like python 2 answer... so..  BTW thanks for help.
In real world may be it is. And **split** behavior is not the same that **strip** is. Or it is?  Say me - I do not know. I mean in part of these default sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.whitespace` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace) as

> A string containing all **ASCII** characters that are considered whitespace. This includes the characters space, tab, linefeed, return, formfeed, and vertical tab.

It only includes ASCII whitespace, not all whitespace.

As documented under [`str.isspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace),

> A character is whitespace if in the Unicode character database (see [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata)), either its general category is Zs (“Separator, space”), or its bidirectional class is one of WS, B, or S.

This is the definition of whitespace used by `str.strip`. All characters with the listed Unicode properties will be stripped from the ends of the string. The code to check for this is [generated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Tools/unicode/makeunicodedata.py) from the Unicode character database and hardcoded into the Python interpreter, so it will reflect whatever version of the Unicode character database was used to build the Python version you're running.

Comment: i just wanna make my python lesson better. before this question is not closed - give me  advice - how can I generate or obtain that full list of ASCII and unicode symbols? Just check for any symbol for some value?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: Your best bet would be to check the source code for your Python version. The generated function is `_PyUnicode_IsWhitespace`, as one of the other answers mentioned. (I don't think any new characters with these character properties have been added since U+205F back in 2002, but that doesn't mean new whitespace won't be added.)

Comment: It is important to note that there are differences between Python's set of Whitespace characters and Unicode. Python's definition has a few C0 control characters classed as whitespace that Unicode does not. So for instance i would expect that the treatment of whitespace in the `re` and `regex` modules would differ.

Answer (score 3):

From the [cypthon source in `unicodetype_db.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/unicodetype_db.h#L6374C1-L6412C2) with inline comments for each character name added by me:

```
/* Returns 1 for Unicode characters having the bidirectional
 * type 'WS', 'B' or 'S' or the category 'Zs', 0 otherwise.
 */
int _PyUnicode_IsWhitespace(const Py_UCS4 ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
    case 0x0009:  // HORIZONTAL TAB
    case 0x000A:  // LINE FEED
    case 0x000B:  // VERTICAL TAB
    case 0x000C:  // FORM FEED
    case 0x000D:  // CARRIAGE RETURN
    case 0x001C:  // FILE SEPARATOR
    case 0x001D:  // GROUP SEPARATOR
    case 0x001E:  // RECORD SEPARATOR
    case 0x001F:  // UNIT SEPARATOR
    case 0x0020:  // SPACE
    case 0x0085:  // NEXT LINE
    case 0x00A0:  // NO-BREAK SPACE
    case 0x1680:  // OGHAM SPACE MARK
    case 0x2000:  // EN QUAD
    case 0x2001:  // EM QUAD
    case 0x2002:  // EN SPACE
    case 0x2003:  // EM SPACE
    case 0x2004:  // THREE-PER-EM SPACE
    case 0x2005:  // FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
    case 0x2006:  // SIX-PER-EM SPACE
    case 0x2007:  // FIGURE SPACE
    case 0x2008:  // PUNCTUATION SPACE
    case 0x2009:  // THIN SPACE
    case 0x200A:  // HAIR SPACE
    case 0x2028:  // LINE SEPARATOR
    case 0x2029:  // PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
    case 0x202F:  // NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
    case 0x205F:  // MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
    case 0x3000:  // IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow! thanks. And I do not remember - is it documentation or variant of realization?
Btw - thanks. I think in 99% it is my symbols set.

Comment: is this the same set for spliting by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
\n = Line break
\t = Tab
\r = Return
```

For the others, I recommend looking up the table @ https://www.scaler.com/topics/escape-sequence-in-python/

Comment: Keep in mind that the string you're printing is probably now "raw", so some character may simply appear as whitespace in your console. Look up documentation if you really want to get in depth.

Comment: I asked full list symbols not explanation ...  `'\x00'.strip()` gives `'\x00`'.  But  `'\x0b'.strip()` gives `''` ...

Comment: Different modules will have different definitions of whitespace. If you are working with the regex module rather than the re module, or if you are using PyICU you will be using the Unicode definition of whitespace rather than Python's definition of whitespace.